# Can you construct a union type with function chaining without losing type-safety?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The idea is:

```js
const todos = createTodoFactory().addTodo("foo").addTodo("bar");
```

The **type** of `todos` should then look like:

```js
{
  addTodo: /* some type */,
  todos: "foo" | "bar"
}
```

This doesn't have to be a function if for some reason a class is more convenient to type.

Comment: What do you mean "without losing type safety?"  Your example is all strings.

Comment: String literals. Typescript can work with them. When a function accepts a generic string and it returns it, the function is not typed to return a string, but to return the string literal you provided. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoCp1XAPBxAUwA8pCxUBnRSqAJxjAHMA+ACjNIC5EMBKRAG8AUIkR1CUEHSScoAbmEBfYcIgJaiMpoC8KdFhxsARMDhxjfIA

Comment: Minimal example of building types: https://tsplay.dev/mLXnZm

Comment: @RobertHarvey [All use of ChatGPT content posted on Stack Overflow is banned.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) Furthermore, the code provided by ChatGPT in that session doesn't work.

Comment: @DoHn I can suggest something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqD2ATeAeW0CmAPALhgdojBDgE4CW+A5gNoC60AvNPQHzQDeAUNNAA4BXAEYhywaDiTwIAQgBccANw9owePhKkBwSaQAUASk4qAvlxVhEiBMhQBpTLgJFomylVZ7JyBXYMKbVBoAOlDYABpoOzp2bl5eHAALcghg72lgwQhErykDZRVeUgwcAVJ8CWSYSGgBfABrfHgAdwqawJQQsMjo1mVeMzMuNQ0cCSkASVGwfGAMJmh8DGa4KUNlEZJoYogBEDHmdKmSGbngy2s1gHIQeBArg3OrQL0bu+gAJge0qQhlAHp-vFoAA9AD85i4OAAnnx5gBVfDkdQAJQwu32Cy8sIw8AAZtt0XscAYaPgBABbIQYUh0LiA4HgoA). Will it work for you?

Comment: @kelsny Your minimal example was enough. Care to make an answer or should I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the most basic way of achieving such an API:

```
class TodoFactory<T extends string = never> {
  todos!: T;

  addTodo<X extends string>(x: X): TodoFactory<T | X> {
    // ...

    return this;
  }
}

const todos = new TodoFactory().addTodo("foo").addTodo("bar").todos;
//    ^? "foo" | "bar"
```

Make the class generic, and have a method that returns the class instance, with some modifications to the generic parameters. You can then use the type parameter where you need the built type.